# WPF Datagrid row number

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid. I would like a column that displays simply 1 2 3 4 ... in the rows, up to as many rows as I have being created from my other data bindings.

```
 <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="#" IsReadOnly="True"
                                           Binding="...."         />
```

Comment: I found an answer as an attribute to the datagrid to show a leading number column. I forget the actual attribute.

Comment: You forget??  That's kind of useless.  Can't you just take a second to look at your program?

Answer (score 4):

I've spent a good chunk of time today looking through MSDN documentation and other threads for this answer.  The way I've settled on implementing this is binding a property (that I created) specifically for line numbers in the objects in the collection that the datagrid is bound to.  e.g.

```
public class myItem
{
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }
    // rest of your object...
}
```

You'll have to manually set the line number in the objects yourself.

Another way of adding line numbers can be found [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/17482/82263.aspx).  Here's the code:

```
datagrid.LoadingRow += 
    new EventHandler<DataGridRowEventArgs>(datagrid_LoadingRow);

...
void datagrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Header = e.Row.GetIndex();
}
```

This implementation puts the line numbers in the row headers and does not require you to put a property just for line numbers in your objects.  However, if you need to insert or delete a row from the datagrid, the line numbers will not update.

Comment: The second does not work. When we scroll up and down, all the header values will be disordered. This is due to internal behavior of DataGrid to improve performance.

Comment: See the discussion at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663771/wpf-4-datagrid-getting-the-row-number-into-the-rowheader/4663799#comment14001342_4663799
for details on why this may or may not work on different versions of DataGrid, based on virtualization setting.

Comment: If you are using MSSQL Server 2005+, you can try: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx