# Show row-number in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` where the `ItemsSource` is bound to an `ObservableCollection<LogEntry>` in the ViewModel. In the `DataGrid` the properties `Message` and `Date` from the `LogEntry`-class are displayed.

The items in this `ItemsSource` are changing very often depending on an outer selection.

Now I want to introduce an additional column in my `DataGrid` which displays the row-number.

Is there a simple way to do this in WPF with MVVM or do I have to create a new class (e.g. `RowLogEntry`) which inherits from `LogEntry` and provides a property for the row-number?

Comment: are you using MVVM ?

Comment: please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add them in the LoadingRow event for the DataGrid

```
 <DataGrid Name="DataGrid" LoadingRow="DataGrid_LoadingRow" ...

    void DataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex()).ToString(); 
    }
```

When items are added or removed from the source list then the numbers can get out of sync for a while

When items are added or removed from the source list then the numbers can get out of sync for a while.[For a fix to this, see the attached behavior here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663771/wpf-4-datagrid-getting-the-row-number-into-the-rowheader/4663799#4663799)

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ...}"
          behaviors:DataGridBehavior.DisplayRowNumber="True">
```

use this instead if you want to count from 1

```
void DataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex()+1).ToString(); 
}
```

Hope this helps