# Alignment of number by center of DataGridRowHeader

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to edit [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4663799/8497844) (scroll at the end of the post), I want that number has a normal format and it has alignment, margin, etc... Here what I changed:

```
            GetVisualChildCollection<DataGridRow>(dataGrid).
                ForEach(d => {
                    Style style = new Style(typeof(DataGridRowHeader));
                    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridRowHeader.HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Right));

                    TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
                    textBlock.Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 5, 0);
                    textBlock.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
                    textBlock.Text = (d.GetIndex() + 1).ToString();

                    d.Header = textBlock;
                    d.HeaderStyle = style;
                });
```

The margin is present. But I have a problem with alignment.

I want to align text at textbox by the right of the row header.

I tried to set the alignment of textbox and row header style but nothing works out.

That is how I want.

[image: Good example]

So I did.

[image: Bad example]

Comment: Use : textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;  Depending on the FONT the allignment will look different.

Comment: @jdweng I follow your advice but It still not work. I used `textBlock.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right;` .